# Why is the focus event fired twice from a Vue 3 child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

When I fire a `focus` event from a top level input field in Vue 3:

```
<input @focus="$emit('focus')">
```

...the event is fired once when the input field is focused (as I would expect).

However, when you put this same input field into a child component and focus it:

```
<InputField @focus="$emit('focus')" />
```

...the event is fired twice.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-wjhche?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Can you please help me to understand why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you shouldn't put a focus event in the child component, and also in the `input` field too, as the child component already will bind its `focus` event to the `input` so the focus event will be called twice, as the `input` is the root element.

Just removing the focus event from the `input` will solve the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-676vsb?file=src/components/InputField.vue

Comment: Thanks - here is the relevant part of the [https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#v-on-listener-inheritance](documentation) that I was missing.